Method inside `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` not getting called
Here is the part of part code. The extension on ViewController has two methods. The first one getting called, but the second one not getting called once startDownload() called.
// Initialising URLSession
private var session: URLSession!
    
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
}

@objc private func startDownload()  {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://files.testfile.org/AUDIO/C/M4A/sample1.m4a") else {
        return
    }
    let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: URLRequest(url: url))
    downloadTask.resume()
}

extension ViewController: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    // This mehthod is getting called
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        print("Finished Downloading")
    }
    
    // This method is not getting called at all
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didSendBodyData bytesSent: Int64, totalBytesSent: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend: Int64) {
        let fractionReceived = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)
        print(fractionReceived)
        progressView.progress = fractionReceived
    }
}



Thanks! got the method names and variables confused.

Please forgive an unrelated observation: Make sure to finishTasksAndInvalidate or invalidateAndCancel when you are done, or else you will leak. And note that URLSession keeps a strong reference to its delegate, so you might do this in, for example, viewDidDisappear, rather than deinit.

The didSendBodyData is for data sent to the web service (commonly used for upload tasks, where you are sending lots of data to the server). I think you want didWriteData delegate method, which reports data received from the server:
func urlSession(
    _ session: URLSession,
    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
    didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
    totalBytesWritten: Int64,
    totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64
) {
    …
}

FYI, be careful, though, as the server will not always report a meaningful totalBytesExpectedToWrite. As the documentation for this parameter says:

The expected length of the file, as provided by the Content-Length header. If this header was not provided, the value is NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown.

Whether this size is provided depends upon the particulars of the server implementation. You might want to check for NSURLSessionTransferSizeUnknown before calculating a percentage, and otherwise use an indeterminate progress indicator and/or just report the kb/mb received thus far.
